what input should I use to predict rl model? will it be scaled or inv scaled?
I am using sb3 DQN to train stock data where my obs is last 120 candle with 7 feature i.e open high low close hour min rsi etc... . so obs shape would be (120,7) output would be discrete with 3 int 0, 1, 2 (Hold, buy, sell respectively).
My questions are:

I am only scaling obs using minmaxscaler is it correct or do I need to scale all data in that case I have 200000 rows of 5 min candle?


here is a scale_data fun in my custom gym env
def scale_data(self,obs):
        df1 = obs
        df1[['OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'rsi', 'TICKVOL']] = scaler.fit_transform(
        obs[['OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'rsi', 'TICKVOL']]) 

        df1[['MINUTE','HOUR','DAY_OF_WEEK']] = obs[['MINUTE','HOUR','DAY_OF_WEEK']]
        
        return df1.values



Another thing is if answer is to scale all data what to pass while prediction as on the time of predication I might not have all of the data and I would like to predict with most recent 120 candle data. If we scale all data and use only last 120 to predict than scaling would be entirely different!

